# Ways to change in dropdown when clicking in the list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to change automatically the alternative in the drop down when i click an alternative in the a list in the left side of the page with Java script ?

Comment: Provide code for what you have tried so others can help with it. If you don't know how, google for a tutorial and post a question when you are having an issue

Comment: Code and more explanation are in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

This part is for reading the data from a web service and showing them the in the screen and also showing alternatives in drop down. The problem is that when i click in the main menu, those alternatives in drop down that are equal to alternatives in the left side of the page dont change automatically. Heres the code for the left side.

"use strict";

var baseURL = "http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
       if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            var jsonData = JSON.parse( xmlhttp.responseText );
            document.getElementById("searchlan").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("searchlan").innerHTML = "<option seleted disabled>Hela Sverige</option>";
            for(var i=0; i < jsonData.soklista.sokdata.length; i++){

               document.getElementById("mainnavlist").innerHTML += "<li id='"+jsonData.soklista.sokdata[i].id+"'>"+jsonData.soklista.sokdata[i].namn+" (" + jsonData.soklista.sokdata[i].antal_ledigajobb + ")</li>";
               document.getElementById("searchlan").innerHTML += "<option value='"+jsonData.soklista.sokdata[i].id+"'>"+jsonData.soklista.sokdata[i].namn+"</option>";


            }
       }
       else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
          alert('There was an error 400');
       }
       else {
           alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
       }
    }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", baseURL+"/platsannonser/soklista/lan", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

});